# Parsing Wiki XML Dumps ver0.4 just got tough

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, mediawiki, wikipedia

I am trying to parse Wikipedia XML Dump using "Parse-MediaWikiDump-1.0.4" along with "Wikiprep.pl" script. I guess this script works fine with ver0.3 Wiki XML Dumps but not with the latest ver0.4 Dumps. I get the following error.

Can't locate object method "page" via package "Parse::MediaWikiDump::Pages" at wikiprep.pl line 390.

Also, under the "Parse-MediaWikiDump-1.0.4" documentation @ http://search.cpan.org/~triddle/Parse-MediaWikiDump-1.0.4/lib/Parse/MediaWikiDump/Pages.pm, I read "LIMITATIONS Version 0.4 This class was updated to support version 0.4 dump files from a MediaWiki instance but it does not currently support any of the new information available in those files."

Any work arounds would help me get to the next level.

Note: one may wonder why cannot we directly use SAX or STAX parser instead, wikipedia dump is a 25GB plus single file, stack/memory issues are obvious. Hence, the above perl script resolves this issue but currently I am stuck with this version problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any streaming parser should work just fine (DOM parsers would blow up).  Try [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig_pm.slow), just remember to flush (if you want to print out the XML) or purge (if you don't care about the XML) after every major record.

Or just use [`XML::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Parser/Parser.pm) directly.  That is what both `XML::Twig` and [`Parse::MediaWikiDump`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-MediaWikiDump/lib/Parse/MediaWikiDump.pm) are using under the hood to parse the XML.

Comment: Thanks very much...this info will be very helpfull indeed, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace "$pages->page" (which occurs twice in the script) with "$pages->next". That kinda did the trick; for me, it finished XXX.hgw.xml, XXX.anchor_text, and XXX.related_links files but then got stuck in a loop...

Correction: looking at the end of my XXX.hgw.xml file, it stopped mid-word...

Answer (score 0):

Use `MediaWiki::DumpFile::Compat` instead of the deprecated `Parse::MediaWikiDump`. For more information, [see here](http://search.cpan.org/~triddle/MediaWiki-DumpFile-0.2.1/lib/MediaWiki/DumpFile/Compat.pm).

And yes, use

```
$pages->next
```

as suggested by Joshua. Worked for me ...

Comment: I know this is a very old discussion. But I'm trying to get Wikiprep.pl to work on Wikipedia's latest dumps.

I replaced the line "use Parse::MediaWikiDump" with "use MediaWiki::DumpFile::Compat" and "->page" with "->next". Is that everything that you were suggesting? It still doesn't work for me so I thought maybe there was something obvious I was missing.